# substructures generated by constant symbols

Tags: model-theory

I am have recently started to learn about model theory, so this might be a stupid question. To learn model theory, I am reading David Marker's Model Theory. This is the situation in the proof of 3.1.4:

We have a model $M$ of a theory $T$. Moreover, we have a set of new constant symbols $d_1,\dots,d_m$. Then, Marker says "Let $A$ be the substructure of $M$ generated by $d_1,\dots,d_m$".

I don't understand how a substructure can be generated by a set of constant symbols as they are part of the Language $L$ not of the domain of $A$. Where is my lack of understanding?

Am I right that substructures are normally generated by giving the domain? Or is it indeed possible to alter the language to generate a substructure?

Comment: Does Marker give any interpretations of the new constant symbols in the model $M$? If so, it's probably just a typo, and he meant to say $d_i^M$ (or whatever notation he uses to indicate the interpretation of a nonlogical symbol in a structure).

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Arthur Fischer's comment, but it would be useful to see more of the context from Marker.

Comment: Marker usually use $v,x,y,z$ to denote *variables* and $a,b,c$ to denote objects of the domain. In this case [page 74], he add the new *constant symbols* $d_1,\ldots, d_m$ but then uses them also for objects : $T \cup \Gamma(\overline d) \vDash \phi(\overline d)$.

Comment: You are right; the definition is of "substructure of $\mathcal M$ *generated by* $X$", where $X \subseteq M$. I think that it is only an "abbreviation" for "Let $\mathcal A$ be the substructure 
of $\mathcal M$ generated by [the *interpretations* of the new *constant symbols*] $\overline d$".